# Get HTTP-method inside of XMLHttpRequest.onload

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Let's suppose I have instance of `XMLHttpRequest` in a global scope.
Also, I have two **disjoint** scopes "A" and "B".

Request instance `request` is available in a global scope.
Then, HTTP-method `method` is defined inside of scope "A".
After that, sending request and handling its `onload` event inside of scope "B".

So, variable `method` is defined inside of "A" and I can't access it from "B".
Is there any way to find out HTTP-method in scope "B" using only `request` instance?

```
/* Global scope starts */

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

/* Scope A starts */

var method = 'POST', // or 'GET' - chosen HTTP-method
    url = '/some/url';

request.open( method, url, true );

/* 
 * Scope A ends
 *
 * [then some code]
 *
 * Scope B starts
 */

request.send();

request.onload = function() {
    /* 
     * Is there any way 
     * to find out HTTP-method here?
     */
}

/* Scope B ends */

/* Global scope ends */
```

Comment: off the top of my head, you could add `request.method = method` .. then in `onload` you should see `this.method`

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, its working variant.
But I wonder is there no way to do it using XMLHttpRequest  built-in methods?

Comment: reading the documentation, I can't see anything that would suggest you can do that - you could monkey patch the `open` method I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could monkey patch the `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` method like so

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = (function(original) {
    // in case this code is called twice
    if (original.name === 'newOpen') {
        return original;
    }
    return function newOpen(method, url, asyncflag, user, password) {
        this.xopen = { method: method, url: url, asyncflag: asyncflag, user: user, password: password };
        return original.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

then

```
request.onload = function() {
    console.log(this.xopen.method); // the method used is output
}
```